# How to achieve springs HttpMessageConverter like functionality in Grails

Tags: spring-mvc, grails, grails-2.0

HttpMessageConverter or one of its implementation can be used to convert the HTTP message body into desired form. How we can achieve the same in Grails such that the converted object type can be used in controller action methods as request body/command object.

Comment: https://guides.grails.org/command-objects-and-forms/guide/index.html

Comment: @cfrick, I did go through the link but it does not mention how to provide your own way to create command object. Is there a way to sneak or hook into Grails command object creation.